# I want to return the result after all the async methods are complete. Any suggestions to run this in sequential manner and get the results

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
async function getResults() {
let result = 'false'
let updateStatus = await update() 
let deleteStatus = await delete() 
let addStatus = await add() 

if(updateStatus == 'success' && deleteStatus == 'success' && addStatus == 'success') {
result = 'success'
}
return result
}
```

//check the response from all the async methods and return success

Comment: Do all the async methods return a promise that is resolved when their asynchronous operations are done?  If so, this should already work for sequencing the operations.  Your function will return a promise that resolves to whatever value you return.

Comment: no, The async method will return the customised response like this {status: ''success"}

Comment: If your methods don't return a promise that resolves when their asynchronous operations are done, then the `await` does absolutely nothing and you have no way to sequence them.  Functions that contain asynchronous operations must communicate back when they are done (and their result or error) either by returning a promise, using a callback or an event system.

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getResults() {
   let status = 'false';
   let updateStatus = await update();    
   let deleteStatus = await delete();
   let addStatus = await add();

   return updateStatus === 'success' && deleteStatus === 'success' &&  addStatus === 'success' ? 'success' : status;
}
```

Of course instead of using the string `'false'` and `'success'` it's easier to just use booleans. And if you don't change a variable, you should use `const`:

```js
async function getResults() {
   const updateStatus = await update();    
   const deleteStatus = await delete();
   const addStatus = await add();

   return updateStatus && deleteStatus && addStatus;
}
```

Even better is to *not* use boolean responses for error conditions, but throw exceptions instead. If you do that, the function turns into this:

```js
async function getResults() {
   await update();    
   await delete();
   await add();
}
```